# Split contents of a cell into rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table with several rows and 4 columns. The contents of some of these cells have multiple lines of data. The structure is as shown below:

[image]

I want to split the contents of the cell and display like below:

[image]

Could someone help me with this?

**EDIT:**

As per my approach, I planned to split the data in col 3 (which are space separated) using "Text to Columns" and then "Paste Transpose". However, I am stuck at this point. I want to Paste Transpose without overwriting the existing cell contents below, in other words, shift the rows below.

Comment: I thought maybe it was possible to have something like Text to Rows with delimiter as new line. But then I would have to copy the contents of the other 3 columns repeatedly.

Comment: How is the text on col 3 split?

Comment: The text on Col 3 is separated through "space". I did a text to columns mapping with delimiter as space. Then I took transpose to print them all in row format. But it is not aligned properly.

Comment: Why does it need to align when you're planning to split it up over different rows

Comment: I mean when I do text to columns and then try to paste transpose,the rows below are overwritten. To be exact, I want to know how to paste columns to row transpose without overwriting the below rows

Comment: I suggest you update your post with that as it may help others to understand what you want and how you want to acheive it :) As I could only solve this with VBa, I don't think I can help but I'm sure some one can :)